# Using Compare-object for file size

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Compare-Object to compare the contents of two folders. I want to find all files with the same Length property.

Easy enough with

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $one  -DifferenceObject $two -Property Length -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
```

but if I only specify Length and not Name as a Property I get "@{Length=0; SideIndicator===}" as the output so I don't know the names of the matching files.

If I use -PassThru it only returns the files that are the same in the -ReferenceObject so I don't have the names of the files in the -DifferenceObject

Am I missing something or just the wrong tool for the job?

Thanks

Comment: I thought you just wanted to compare the two folders. What's the issue if you have all the matching files, but not the additional files from the differenceobject? Do you want All Files from FolderB but want to know which also have matches in FolderA?

Comment: Do you want to find all the files of the same length, or all the files of the same name that have the same length?

Comment: I want the file names from folderA and folderB where the file sizes are the same but the names are different, i.e. fileA.txt and fileB.txt are a match if both 10 bytes in size.

Comment: It sounds like you need to first group by length, then compare groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, mjolinor, groups were the key.
This isn't 100% what I was after but does a good enough job.

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\temp1, c:\temp2 | Group-Object -Property length

foreach($filegroup in $allfiles)
{
    if ($filegroup.Count -ne 1)
    {
        foreach ($file in $filegroup.Group)
        {
            Invoke-Item $file.fullname
        }
    }
}
```